# How to comment options in org-mode export to beamer?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Generally in the LaTeX or `beamer` preamble, we add some packages and options for reference and enable them if required.

```
%\usepackage{someusefulpackage}
```

In Org mode export to LaTeX or `beamer`, when I specify options in the file header, how to comment them out

```
#+BEAMER_COLOR_THEME: dove
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{usefulPkg}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{notRequired}
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
```

How can I comment out some of them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply add a `#` in front.  You will have to restart Org though for this to take effect.

Note that 'restarting Org' is exactly what `C-c C-c` on one of these lines would normally do.

```
#+BEAMER_COLOR_THEME: dove
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{usefulPkg}
# #+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{notRequired}
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
```

Comment: Cant believe its that simple and not mentioned anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: @Anusha [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. :)

Comment: Would you know how to export slide with option fragile or allowpagebreaks when including bibliography ?

Comment: @Anusha Unfortunately no :( But that is a separate question in any case.  You should ask a new one (after marking this one as answered, of course) :)

Comment: Yes ofcourse. I thought if its this straightforward, it is better to ask here only. Thanks.

Comment: If it's a separate question, it's *always* better to ask a separate question :) it's what keeps the site tidy.